# 'Get Add-Ins' button disabled on Outlook (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I noticed that the Get Add-Ins button was missing from my version of Outlook, so I added it in to a custom ribbon. Now when I go to it, the button is greyed out/disabled.

I read online that this is usually to do with an admin user, however I have tried opening Outlook as admin and also in safe mode.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the specific build you are using in the question body by editing your question.

Comment: What’s your account type? This option is available for Exchange account.